# Query that will identify rows that should be identical (Except with 2 exceptions)

Tags: sql

we have a customer table and some customers appear multiple times if they are available for multiple offices. If someone adds a customer multiple times, I want to be able to run a report to see if they have done it correctly for each location, but I don't really have a clue where to start. Here is an example

```
UID, Office,          CustomerCode, CUSTOMERNAME,      CUSTOMERHEADOFFICEPHONE
001, Manchester,  123,                 123 Supplied Ltd,   0161 123456
002, London,        123,                 123 Suppls Ltd,     0161 123446
```

So we can sell stuff to customer '123' from both our Manchester and London offices. The report should focus on the CustomerCode and make sure whenever '123' appears all the CAPITAL rows should be the same with the exception of UID (Always different), Office (Naturally that is different). So the report would see that not all the CustomerNames are identical and they have also made a mistake on the CustomerHeadOfficePhone. If I had thousands of rows and all the other 'multi-customers' matched up, I'd want my report to just show these 2 rows. How would I go about that please?

Comment: The exact syntax depends on your variant of SQL, but I think you are looking for a GROUP BY, and then a HAVING clause. WHERE and HAVING are similar, but WHERE does the filter on the individual rows before returning them, and HAVING does the filter after you group them. So you'd probably want HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 or something like that. I can give an answer if you want, but it seems all you need is a hint.

Comment: Thank you, I'll draft something up and come back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
select CustomerCode, CustomerName, CustomerHeadOfficePhone, count(*)
from TableName
group by CustomerCode, CustomerName, CustomerHeadOfficePhone
having count(*) > 1
```

That will list every occurrence of the records with different values, which you would need if you were going to delete them. You could shorten the list by using DISTINCT, and you could present the UIDs in a better way with an additional query around this one. But it seems that you have only asked for the list of things to fix, and I believe this will give it to you.